# Emulate 960x640(Normal screen xhdpi)

Tags: android, android-emulator

Current ADT plugin doesn't allow creating Normal screen xhdpi virtual devices. However, I need  to ensure everything's fine.

Could you show me how I can achieve creating this configuration?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Emulate 960x640(Normal screen xhdpi) Current ADT plugin doesn't allow creating Normal screen xhdpi virtual devices

Yes you are Right. AFAIK you can Only create Emulator With Given Below suggestions with Density 
While Creatinf AVD you will get Below Image. you can only choose from the Below Devices to make your Emulator.

[image]

**Your Alternative Solution :**

> **However, I need to ensure everything's fine.**

Yes you can Surely get what you want.

if you want to Check whether your application runs perfectly on  960x640(Normal screen xhdpi) Device. you can Make Custom Configuration From Below Suggestion.

After Update your ADT to version 21.

**In Older Version each time you have to set `Add Custom` Screen if you want custom Device Configurations as (if you want Nexus 4).**

In ADT21 version you can get this thing done by

> **open `AVD Manager`, u can define your custom screen in `"Device Definition"`**

**Alternative (Much Easier approach)**

> in Newest Version you Don't Need to Set Custom Device
>   Configurations from the above Suggestion as much easier way is available for it. you >Just Have to Make Emulator With your Device 
>   Configurations and after you will see those Configurations with
>   Emulator Name Inside `Graphical Layout` of XML

like after Created my Emulator of Nexus7 Emulator with Android 4.2 with Name as "Nexus7_Android_4.2" i will get this Device Configuration in Graphical Layout of xml automatically.

Below is the Screen Shot of it.

[image]

Hope it will Help you.